# Selenium IDE > Selblocks plugin > in if command how can evaluate if a variable is true or not

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I am creating a script where I am defining 2 variables.
I want to evaluate one of them to see if is true to do something and if not to do something else. 
I am evaluating with verify element present and it works (value is true) but when I am writing to check inside if to see if element is true it goes to else (seeing it as false). What am I doing wrong ?

```
<tr>
    <td>verifyElementPresent</td>
    <td>${c}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${c}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>if</td>
    <td>storedVars['c']==true</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>Taking position: ${c}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAt</td>
    <td>id=${c}</td>
    <td></td>
```

[See Attached my Selenium script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIkgD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeElementPresent</td>
    <td>${e}</td>
    <td>elementPresent</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>if</td>
    <td>${elementPresent} == true</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Frankly I think you're better off doing this in javascript and then setting the selenium variable there than trying to for IF functionality into IDE.

An example:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>my_date = Date.now();&nbsp;&nbsp;console.log(my_date); if(my_date % 2 == 0) {&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;console.log(&quot;even&quot;);&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&quot;even&quot;; } else {&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;console.log(&quot;odd&quot;);&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&quot;odd&quot;; }</td>
    <td>my_var</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${my_var}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I really prefer to work with Javascript code instead of IDE, but where / how  do I need to include the javascript code ?...is there a specific input file ? how can be created ?..I don't really understand how to work with Javascript in Selenium IDE..any help will be appreciated..

Comment: depends on your goal. You could do something like this:
<tr>
 <td>storeEval</td>
 <td>my_date = Date.now();&nbsp;&nbsp;console.log(my_date); if(my_date % 2 == 0) {&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;console.log(&quot;even&quot;);&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&quot;even&quot;; } else {&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;console.log(&quot;odd&quot;);&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&quot;odd&quot;; }</td>
 <td>my_var</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>echo</td>
 <td>${my_var}</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>